# RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, node-modules, nodejs-server

I need to decrypt a message with the following logic

**Logic**
RSA/ECB/PKCS1Decryption(Base64Decode(encryptedKey),B2C.cer)

Tried with two modules crypto & node-RSA returns a similar error.

RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error

**Code**

const privateKeyForDecryption = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./nsBank.key"));

// node-rsa module

```
function RSA_Decrypt(str){
    var key = new nodeRSA(privateKeyForDecryption);

    key.setOptions({encryptionScheme:'pkcs1'});

    const decrypted = key.decrypt(str, 'base64');

    return decrypted;
}
```

**Error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBYuO.png)
// crypto module

```
function RSA_Decrypt(str){
    const buffer = Buffer.from(str,"base64");
    const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt({key:privateKeyForDecryption,padding:crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING}, buffer);
    return decrypted;
}
```

**Error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqgVd.png)

Comment: There isn't nearly enough here to figure out the problem. Maybe you are using the wrong private key, maybe the data is corrupted, maybe your decryption does not match up with the encryption.

Comment: #1privateKey - This private key works with another context. So we can't suspect private key. #2corrupteddata - There is a chance to occur it is a string from a response object. we have to perform base64 decoding. Is there any mistake in base64 decoding. this is m first code. #3 Encryption Decryption Mismatch - Could you please help me to verify the code snippet with the LOGIC (RSA/ECB/PKCS1Decryption(Base64Decode(encryptedKey),B2C.cer)) in Decryption.